# PHP Code not reading URL

Tags: php

I have a simple while loop I'm using to generate dynamic menus using PHP.

The dummy code example works just fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>linkpuller.php</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $allMenus = array("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot");
        $i = 0;
        while ((strpos(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), $allMenus[$i]) == false) ) {
            $i++;
        }
        $pathResult = $allMenus[$i];
    ?>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores deserunt cum blanditiis saepe, pariatur aliquam maiores eos obcaecati ratione sit provident quisquam, ipsa autem tempore quod animi, cupiditate numquam minus.</p>

    <?php
        echo "<h1>$pathResult $i</h1>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This I tested by calling `linkpuller.php?v=fooalphabar` and it works fine but if I name the file `alpha.php` it runs for 30 seconds and times out.  I'm assuming this is because PHP treats paths different than parameters but is there a way to get this to work?  "Echo" is showing that it does pull indeed pull "alpha" from the while loop.  I've also tried other things like `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` or `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` or setting a variable to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but no dice.

Comment: If the point of this is to loop over the `$allMenus` array, why don't you do that instead of running a potentially infinite loop? At least that way you'll limit your iterations to the size of the array

Comment: What is the *purpose* of the code? You want to use `===` operator when comparing strpos, because it can return `false` OR `0` which both equate to false. And if it never matches, it also will never end. You're better off using `foreach` instead of `while`.

Comment: Closing as typo. Correct comparison operator is `===` as shown in the [docs](http://php.net/strpos).

Comment: My logic in not using for or foreach was because then it will still evaluate after finding the match.  So if it matches on the first one it won't need to go after the other five. === did indeed solve the problem though...man it's always something stupid!  RadGH if you post that as an answer...

Comment: You can use `break;` to close out of a loop,  or `continue;` to stop the current iteration of a loop, but still performing other iterations.

Comment: I know but that's not a reason to do it that way.  I'm not saying you're wrong I'm saying I don't see the difference.

Comment: @scrowler I don't need to go through the entire array.  Only need to find the one match.  The pages have custom menus by section and each page contains in its path the name of its section.  Once I know what section I'm in, problem solved.  Don't need the rest of the data.  (And I didn't set this up, am refactoring to make it easier to update.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It remains unclear what the goal of your code is, but the code below is very similar and utilizes a `foreach` instead of a `while` loop. If the current page matches what is found in `$allMenus`, the menu name will be stored in `$current`.

The last couple of lines are for testing.

```
$allMenus = array("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot");
$current = false;

foreach($allMenus as $menu_name) {
  // Check if the $menu_name appears at the beginning of the REQUEST_URI.
  if ( strpos(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), $menu_name) === 0 ) {
    $current = $menu_name;
    break; // Stop running the loop, we're done
  }
}

if ( $current ) echo  'The current page is: ' . $menu_name;
else echo 'No menu page was found';

// Test results:
// http://example.org/alpha.php      -- The current page is: alpha
// http://example.org/not-alpha.php  -- No menu page was found
```

Comment: The answer I'm looking to accept is the one where you point out I needed ===.  Not too convinced that "for" beats" "while" here.  See my comments above.  Open to any explanation you might provide, of course.

Comment: A foreach is easier to read. If you are iterating through each item in an array it does a good job and is clear in what is happening and how to access the current index of the array (in this case, `$menu_name`). You also do not need the `$i` counter, and a foreach would even work with associative arrays. It's just suited for this type of a loop. That doesn't mean you can't use a `while` or a standard `for` loop (not to be confused with `forEACH`).

Comment: No offense but I'm not confused about the differences between for, foreach and while.  I don't need to iterate through every item.  Just need the loop to go until it finds the one it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Also providing better option:

Rather than leaving yourself prone to such infinite loops, try:

```
$pathResult = null;
foreach($allMenus as $item) {
    if( strpos(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), $item) !== false) {
        $pathResult = $item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comments above.  I don't need to go through the rest of the data. So I'm not sure I see how breaking out of a "for" is better than terminating a "while" but am open to any explanation you might have.

Comment: Your `while` is vulnerable to infinite loops. `foreach` is guaranteed to terminate.